# Multi-cursor Editing possibility in MATLAB Editor?

Tags: matlab, editor

Is there a way to multiline edit code in matlab, Instead of copy-paste a single line repeatedly, or copy paste from matlab to visual studio editor to take advantage of the visual studio's <kbd>alt</kbd> + `cursor select`?

Comment: Are you referring to the [multi-cursor ability in visual basic](https://code.visualstudio.com/images/editingevolved_multicursor.gif)?

Comment: @Johannes right, multi-cursor in general, it's not just in visual basic or visual studio. Just refered to visual studio ide as an example.

Comment: Currently not available in Matlab, you should not need it either if you need to set multiple variables to the same value, use a matrix (or higher order matrix in the case where you want to assign a matrix to it).

Comment: You can specify a custom editor in File->Preferences->Editor/Debugger and then use that for all editing. You should even be able to specfiy the Visual Studio editor although you'd likely lose proper syntax highlighting. vim and other alternatives have this same functionality *as well as* proper syntax highlighting and linting

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick mention that MATLAB officially support multi-line cursor since R2018a, just hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and hold <kbd>left mouse button</kbd> (also Alt+Shift in linux) to draw a column selection across multiple lines.

[image: multi-line selection]

Comment: It is supported in live-editor from [release R2018a](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html?rntext=rectangular&startrelease=R2018a&endrelease=R2018a&category=desktop&groupby=release&sortby=descending&searchHighlight=rectangular).

Comment: Alt+Shift in linux