# Select Text in vertical in Matlab text Editor

Tags: matlab, text-editor

Is there a way for selecting text in vertical in Matlab Text Editor?
What I mean is something equivalent to Alt+Shift in Atom text editor for example:

### [image]

Even a hack is appreciated. What I do normally (when I need this functionality) is to open the same text-file with Atom. But, of course, to be able to modify inside the same Matlab can make me save time.

Comment: even a hack is appreciated :) what I do normally (when I need this functionality) is to open the same text-file with Atom. But, of course, to be able to modify inside the same Matlab can make me save time

Comment: I understand you might even appreciate a hack, I am still curious though why you would ever need to highlight text this way in any editor?

Comment: In this particular case, I need to add the same variable as a first argument of the function barh(X,......) that you can see in the picture. There are more than 100 line that I would love to edit at the same time

Comment: If you have 100 separate lines calling something that similar, you probably should be using a loop over a cell array of objects! But alright, I think I understand

Comment: In the MATLAB preferences dialog you can change what editor is used when you type `edit`on the command line. I'm sorry to say that this is the best option. The MATLAB editor will still be used by the debugger.

Comment: @Wolfie, there are a lot of different way of doing the same thing. What I want is just an instrument more to use :) for example, Eclipse and Geany also have this functionality !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multi-cursor Editing possibility in MATLAB Editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035132/multi-cursor-editing-possibility-in-matlab-editor)

Comment: it does, right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from MATLAB version R2021b, not only the *live editor*, but also the *editor* allows column selection using the mouse while pressing the ALT-key (or the Option-key on MacOS).

A description of this feature can be found here:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/edit-and-format-code.html